# Waiting for nested AFNetworking calls and for loops to finish

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

So, I've been searching all over but didn't find a solution, or at least I couldn't apply it.
I've found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059975/gcd-poor-performance) here on stackoverflow, but didn't succeed in implementing it in my code.

My issue is, that I need to know when nested AFNetworking calls and For loops are done. I've tried it with GCD groups, but with no luck.
The code looks like this:

```
{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        [[JSON GET method using AFNetworking 2.0] success:^(NSArray *result) {
            dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
                //do some work with the result

                for (NSDictionary *resultPartDictionary in result) {
                    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
                        //do some more work with parts of the result

                        [[JSON GET method based on result] success:^(NSArray *result) {
                            dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
                                //do some work

                                for (NSDictionary *resultPartDictionary in result) {
                                    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
                                        //do some work

                                        [[JSON GET method based on result] success:^(NSArray *result) {
                                            dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
                                                //do some work

                                                for (NSDictionary *resultPartDictionary in result) {
                                                    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
                                                        //do some work
                                                    });
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }];
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }];
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Right now, everything works. I'm handling Core Data inside the blocks, so I needed MOCs for every thread, which works as well.

The only thing I'd like to know is how to know when all these blocks finish.
Thank you!

**EDIT**

So, I've tried using `dispatch_group_enter(group)` and `dispatch_group_leave(group)`, but it seems to me, that it's just not possible with this embedded architecture. Because of the For loops, the "leave" notifications are either too many, which causes an exception or not enough and the `dispatch_group_notify` returns too early.
Any ideas on this?

Comment: What about a delegate method?

Comment: Could you give some more info about it? I'm fairly new to obj c, and don't really understand what you mean. Thank you!

Comment: Your code executes a task "A", which returns an array of N results, which in turn simultaneously starts N tasks "B" which each returns an array of K(N) results, which each in turn starts K(N) tasks "C" and so force. Are there any requirements regarding the order of these tasks, e.g. should any task "C" only started after _all_ tasks B have finished? What if a task fails? Should others proceed?

Comment: There are no requirements regarding the order, as each is only dependent on the information it gets when it's started and then finishes on it's own. If a task fails, that doesn't have any consequences for others, they should proceed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for `dispatch_group_notify` and `dispatch_group_enter`/`dispatch_group_leave`.

- `dispatch_group_notify` executes the given block in the given queue, when every block in the group is finished.
- `dispatch_group_enter` increases the current count of executing tasks in the group. Every `dispatch_group_enter` must be balanced with a call  to `dispatch_group_leave`.
- `dispatch_group_leave` decreases the current count of executing tasks in the group.

So, you should trick `dispatch_group_notify` with increase the number of the tasks in the group before your network calls start and decrease it when everything finished. To achieve this, call `dispatch_group_enter` before `dispatch_async` and call `dispatch_group_leave` in the last thread. Since you know the element count of the every result array, you can check if the current thread is the last one.

```
dispatch_group_enter(group); // Increases the number of blocks in the group.
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
   // Make your AFNetworking calls.
    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
          //do some work. 
          if (isLastThread)
               dispatch_group_leave(group); // Decreases the number of blocks in the group.
    });
});

dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // Calls the given block when all blocks are finished in the group.
     // All blocks finished, do whatever you like.
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to get this to work. With a simpler method, it works, but with this embedded architecture I can't seem to get it right, will tinker it to see.

Comment: This can't seem to be working with this architecture, see my edit. But thanks anyway!

Comment: If you don't try to notified in every step, don't make it that complicated (Also it won't work that way). Call `dispatch_group_enter` before the first  `dispatch_async`. Then in your last for loop check if it's the last iteration (changing `forin` to `for` can help) and only if so call `dispatch_group_leave`.

Comment: But the last for loop "runs again" because it is in another for loop, so if I fire a 'leave' there, it will think it's done, though it isn't... No?

Comment: OK i see your point now and you are right. But you know the count of every result, so you can still check if it is the last iteration.

Comment: That's was a great idea. :) although, if I put it in the last for loop, it threw an exception, but moving it out of the for loop did the trick. Thank you very much ujell! (Also, if you edit your answer to be one for the question we solved here, I'll accept it gladly!)

Comment: I added some more information to my post, i'm glad it helped.  `dispatch_group_notify` will still wait the new threads you created in the for loop to finish, so it shouldn't be problem.